# copying all mp3s recursively into a single folder in Windows

Tags: windows-console

I have a bunch of music on my windows machine that is organized in folders by artist and then by album. I would like to copy all of the mp3s recursively from all the folders and sub-folders under a main directory into a single location.

Can this be done with windows command line?

Comment: I recommend using powershell to do this, it comes preinstalled with windows.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know what the syntax would be?

Answer (score 1):

let's say that we have the following structure

- c:\temp\1\musicfile.mp3
- c:\temp\2\goodmusicfile.mp3
- c:\temp\3\verygoodfile.mp3
- c:\temp\whatever\what.mp3

and we want to copy all those file to a single directory in

- c:\temp\all

create a bat file inside the c:\temp\ for example copyallmp3.bat and write the following code

```
for /R "C:\temp" %%i in (*.mp3) do xcopy "%%i" "C:\temp\all" /y
```

run copyallmp3.bat.
If you navigate to c:\temp\all you will see all your 4 mp3 files.

If you want the final result to be something like (recursively)

- c:\temp\all\1\musicfile.mp3
- c:\temp\all\2\goodmusicfile.mp3
- c:\temp\all\3\verygoodfile.mp3
- c:\temp\all\whatever\what.mp3

use the following code in powershell

```
$Source = 'C:\temp'
$Files = '*.mp3'
$Dest = 'C:\temp\all'
Get-ChildItem $Source -Filter $Files -Recurse | ForEach{
    $Path = ($_.DirectoryName + "\") -Replace [Regex]::Escape($Source), $Dest
    If(!(Test-Path $Path)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Path -Force | Out-Null
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Path -Force
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inspired me to do a similar task. I move the directories and the files contain a list of file format towards my new destination. Then I delete the empty folders afterwards.

```powershell
$Source = 'D:\Téléchargements'
$Dest = 'D:\Musique'
# List of file format
$File = '*.mp3', '*.flac'

Get-ChildItem "$Source\*" -Include $File -Recurse –force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach{
    $FilePath = $_.DirectoryName
    # File directly in source dir
    If ($FilePath -eq $Source) { Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Dest -Force }
    Else {
        $DestPath = ("$FilePath\") -Replace [Regex]::Escape($Source), $Dest
        If ( !(Test-Path $DestPath) ) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestPath -Force | Out-Null }
        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $DestPath -Force
        # Delete empty dir 
        If ((Get-ChildItem $FilePath).count -eq 0) { Remove-Item $FilePath -Force}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows console the command is

```
xcopy "*".mp3 $from $to
```

**$from** it should be the path of your destination source

**$to** it should be the new path for your source

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your directories are structured `artist/album/*.mp3`:

Make a directory for the copied files

```
mkdir new
```

Go to your music directory

```
cd g:/music
```

Append your `.mp3` with three wildcard characters `*` separated by `\`:

```
cp "*/*/*.mp3" "g:/new"
```

Comment: Please see [formatting help](/help/formatting) for instructions on how to use Stack Overflow's markdown syntax. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Per @PranavHosangadi's note, I've edited your post to improve the formatting. Please take a look at the edits I've made so you can apply similar formatting to your own posts in the future. And, once again, welcome.